# least common multiple of elements of a set

Tags: number-theory

We are given a set $S$ comprising of positive integers and a number $x$. We need to find out if  we can select some elements from $S$ in such a way that their least common multiple will be precisely $x$.

```
          {2,3,4,5}
              20
           We can obtain 20 in multiple ways. One of them: 20 = lcm(4, 5).
           RETURNS POSSIBLE



          {100,200,300,400,500,600}
          8000
             Returns: "Impossible"
```

Comment: For $x=7$ this is impossible. What exactly is your question ? Just form all possible lcm's of your set elements, and check if $x$ is contained.

Comment: then say impossible but what if it possible in other cases

Comment: If it's possible, do what @DietrichBurde just said.

Comment: @DietrichBurde i edited

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suspect this is in fact a programming question. In that case your approach is $O(2^n)$ and probably too slow

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to reach the goal $x$, then one suitable subset is the set of all $y\in S$ with $y\mid x$. So you may simply select all divisors of $x$ from $S$ and compute their lcm.

For example, $2,4,5$ are divisors of $20$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(2,4,5)=20$. And $100,200,400,500\mid 8000$, but $\operatorname{lcm}(100,200,400,500)=2000\ne 8000$.